# Not able to update Group Photo using Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to update the photo of an Office 365 Unified Group using the Graph API:

```
await _graphClient.Groups[groupId].Photo.Content.Request().PutAsync(photoStream);
```

When I try to call this method using an **application permission** token I get:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: ErrorAccessDenied
>   Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.

When I try to call this method using a **delegated token** I get:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: ErrorItemNotFound
>   Message: The specified object was not found in the store., No photo with class 'IPM.UserPhoto.Preview' exists.

The Azure AD App has delegated and application permissions for "Read and Write all groups" as stated in the [docu article](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_update).

[image]

Updating the title and the description of the group is working with both methods (application and delegated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error when using the delegated token occured because of a memorystream which was somehow corrupted. It worked after changing the loading of the stream object. The error message is missleading.

I'm still not sure why the delegated token is not working in this case.